# Problems with a program that decodes resistance by color in C

Tags: c, decoder

I've hit a complete roadblock on this, I'm not entirely good with pointers and file handling atm and uni. was moving too fast that I can't keep up...

Expected input from the file is any of the colors from the array:
input.txt
red, green, blue
black, white, gray
...

which then outputs to a file:
output.txt
red, green, blue
Resistance in ohms: 7000000.000000

black, white, gray
Resistance in ohms: 1000000.000000
...

my output right now:
red, green, blue
Resistance in ohms: 0.000000

black, white, gray
Resistance in ohms: 0.000000

so far here is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<math.h>
#define size 100

double DecodeString(char *inputString){
  const char *kColorTable[10] = {"black", "brown", "red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue", "violet", "gray", "white"};
  int i;

  for(i=0; i<10; i++){
    if(strcmp(inputString, kColorTable[i]) == 0){
      return (double)i;
    }
  }
  return -999.0;
}

int main(){
  char color[size], *token, *inputString;
  double resistance, color1, color2, color3;
  double value;


  FILE *fptrin, *fptrout;
  if(((fptrin = fopen("input.txt", "r"))==NULL) || ((fptrout = fopen("output.txt", "w")) == NULL)){
    printf("Error 404: File not found");
    exit(1);
  }

  while(fgets(color, size, fptrin)){
    token = strtok(color, ",");
    DecodeString(token);
    puts("");
    while(token != NULL){
      value = DecodeString(token);
      printf("%s",token);
      token = strtok(NULL, ",");
    }
  }
  //value = DecodeString(color);

  if (color1 == -999.0 || color2 == -999.0 || color3 == -999.0){
    printf("\n\nBad code -- cannot compute resistance\n");
  }

  else{
    resistance = (10.0 * color1 + color2) *pow(10.0, color3);

    if(resistance > 1000){
      printf("\n\nResistance in Kilo-ohms: %f\n",resistance);
    }
    else{
      printf( "\n\nResistance in ohms: %f\n",resistance);
    }
  }

  fclose(fptrin);
  fclose(fptrout);

  getchar();
  return 0;
}
```

I'm stuck on my strtok loop, I'm not entirely sure how to pass those values into the function and assigning the values from the function to `color1`, `color2`, `color3` to use to calculate the ohms.

I don't understand when I pass `token` to `DecodeString` it only returns the value of the first string and not each individual string (perhaps I'm missing a for loop)

I have another code where I based my code off of someone's function:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<strings.h>
#include<math.h>
#define size 100

double DecodeString(char *inputString)
{
     const char *kColorTable[11] =
     {"", "black", "brown", "red", "orange", "yellow",
      "green", "blue", "violet", "gray", "white"};
     int i;

     for(i=0; i<11; i++)
     {
         if(strcmp(inputString, kColorTable[i]) == 0)
         {
             return (double)i;
         }
     }
     return -999.0;

}

int main(void){
  char color[size], *token, *inputString;
  double value;

  FILE *fptrin, *fptrout;
  if(((fptrin = fopen("input.txt", "r")) == NULL) || ((fptrout = fopen("output.txt", "w")) == NULL)){
    printf("Error 404: File not found");
    exit(1);
  }

  while(fgets(color, size, fptrin)){
    token = strtok(color, ",");
    DecodeString(token);
    puts("");
    while(token != NULL){
      value = DecodeString(token);
      printf("%s",token);
      token = strtok(NULL, ",");
    }
    //value = DecodeString(token);
    printf("%f\n",value + value) *pow(10.0, value);
  }
    return 0;
}
```

I've hit a serious roadblock and would appreciate some explanation and examples to better understand what's going on.

Comment: Please give the test input, the expected output and the actual output.

Comment: I've added the input and output already...

Comment: If the input contains spaces as wells as commas that you want to use as separators then then you should include a space in the second [strtok](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/) parameter e.g: `token = strtok(color, " ,");`

Comment: Why don't you at least attempt to set the `colorX` variables?

Comment: `decodeString` returns 0 for `black` — is that what you wanted? If you report the value in kΩ, don't you need to divide by 1000 too?

Comment: well I'm not entirely sure how to set the colorX variables to the values taken from the file passed through the function.

Comment: The only kind of vehicle that will take you anywhere is a debugger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following logic will work for you,

1.Declare double array

`double colord[3];`

2.Now modify while loop,

```
while(fgets(color, size, fptrin)){
    token = strtok(color, ",");
    colord[i] = DecodeString(token);
    puts("");
    while(token != NULL){
        i++;
        colord[i] = DecodeString(token);
        printf("%s",token);
        token = strtok(NULL, ",");
    }
}
if (colord[0] == -999.0 || colord[1] == -999.0 || colord[2] == -999.0){
    printf("\n\nBad code -- cannot compute resistance\n");
}
else{
    resistance = (10.0 * colord[0] + colord[1]) * pow(10.0, colord[2]);
```

Comment: Thanks! this works for me! I can't believe I didn't think of setting color as an array! Uni. is moving too fast I almost can't keep up! I'll keep practicing and learning!